# What is the story of Panavattam under Shiva Lingam?

Tags: shiva

Is there a story of Panavatta that we keep under Shiva Linga in temples?

Panavatta also gets the  equal importance as Shiva lingam by attaching itself continuously to the Shiva Linga.

Whatever we pour on top of Shiva Linga also goes through Panavatta, so what is the story of Panavatta and is it mentioned in our scriptures anywhere?